# opencart controller and children

Tags: php, opencart

I have two questions:

In a controller `ControllerMainIndex` in opencart we do define

```
$this->children = array("common/footer");
```

Then how should I utilize it in the main/index.tpl file?

It is a little bit vague for me. We have told the controller to get footer but in the main file how should we specify their position?

Second question, I create controller ControllerMasterNewPage and then in I $this->render() (after setting the template to "master/newpage.tpl").

But how should I access this controller? I means what should be typed in the browser for this controller to be process and have output?

Answer (score 1):

1) Just call `<?php echo $footer ?>` it will output that child content

2) http://example.com/index.php?route=path/MasterNewPage/actionName

e.g.: We have file in `{root}/catalog/controller/product/category.php` (class name `ControllerProductCategory`), call it: http://example.com/index.php?route=product/category

Comment: the the opencar itslef beautifies the URL?

Comment: @MT-Developer What you mean "beautifies"? SEO friendly url (like httep://example.com/categoryName) is only applied if SEO url selected in admin panel

Comment: @MT-Developer - It only makes the URL's SEO friendly if they are categories, info pages, manufacturer links and products